# Unable to find the proper syntax to use now() in mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a column "received_on" defined as type "datetime" in the Mysql database and I am trying to insert the value of now() in that field.

In the PHP block, I am using

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO goods_receipts (product, qty, received_on) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $_POST["product"], $_POST["qty"], now());
```

In the HTML form, I am using

```
 input type="text" name="product"
 input type="text" name="qty"
```

I do not have any input defined in the HTML form for the received_on element.

When I attempt to run this, I am getting a syntax error on that now().
I am clearly messing up on the syntax on how to update the received_on column with the value of now() WITHOUT any user input but cannot figure out where. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) is a MySQL function so it is just part of your query and does not need to be prepared:

```
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, "INSERT INTO goods_receipts (product, qty, received_on) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST["product"], $_POST["qty"]);
```

Comment: perfect - that worked like a charm - thank you immensely - just had to use one less "s" in the  mysqli_stmt_bind_param ...